# after:Date not accepting same date in Laravel form validation?

Tags: php, validation, date, laravel, laravel-5

I am using `laravel` form validation method for date validation and working fine. but `after:date` not accepting same date or equal date. but in most case we want to check to date should be equal or less than from date.

```
    public function rules() {

   return [
        'date' => ['required', 'date_format:"d-m-Y"', 'before:return_date'],
        'return_date' => ['date_format:"d-m-Y"', 'after:date']
    ];
}
```

How it validate in `laravel` built in validation method?

Or should I write custom validation method?

Comment: simply don't specify after:date in rules

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try somthing like this

```
public function rules() {
$timestampAfter = strtotime(Input::get('date'));
$dateAfter = $timestampAfter ? date("d-m-Y", $timestampAfter - 86400) : 'date';
   return [
        'date' => ['required', 'date_format:"d-m-Y"', 'before:return_date'],
        'return_date' => ['date_format:"d-m-Y"', 'after:' . $dateAfter]
    ];
}
```